Local storage is not defined when try to fire any http request in AppComponent in Angular 17
In Angular 17 running in Docker I've got standalone AppComponent that contains <router-outlet></router-outlet>.
When I try to subscribe to any http request in app.component.ts, app doesn't rebuild and throws an error:
_Observable {
   source: _Observable {
     source: _Observable {
       source: [_Observable],
       operator: [Function (anonymous)]
     },
     operator: [Function (anonymous)]
   },
  operator: [Function (anonymous)]
}

ERROR ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined

how I try to subscribe to http request: this._authService.isAdmin().subscribe()
isAdmin() method in my service:
  isAdmin(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get(LARAVEL_URL + '/api/auth/isAdmin')
  }

Anyway the same problem with any request. While this error persists localStorage in DevTools becomes empty.
I also have interceptor and AuthGuard that guards component at the route '/'.
Interceptor:
export const authInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (
  req: HttpRequest<any>,
  next: HttpHandlerFn
): Observable<HttpEvent<any> | any> => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');

  if(token) {
    const cloned = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    });
    return next(cloned);
  } else {
    return next(req);
  }
};

AuthGuard:
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService, 
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (this.authService.isAuthenticated()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/auth']);
      return false;
    }
  }
}

How my routes are guarded:
  { path: '', component: MainComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},

How I provide my authInterceptor:
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([authInterceptor]), withFetch()),
  ],
};

I tried to perform http request in another component and import it to AppComponent but it still got the same error.
It's important to make request at app component becuase eventually I want to wrap routerOutlet with MatSideNav from material UI and make my whole app contain sideNavigation. In order to switch content of matSideNav I need http request.

On the server localStorage is non existant, so we should check ifs the server and set a default value and avoid accessing the localStorage! We can perform this check by using the below function and token! You could store the token in a service and access that directly instead of localstorage when on the server, so that the API calls do not fail!
isPlatformBrowser
PLATFORM_ID
export const authInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (
  req: HttpRequest<any>,
  next: HttpHandlerFn
): Observable<HttpEvent<any> | any> => {
  const platformId = inject(PLATFORM_ID);
  const token =  isPlatformBrowser(platformId) ? localStorage.getItem('auth_token') : 'some default auth token';

  if(token) {
    const cloned = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    });
    return next(cloned);
  } else {
    return next(req);
  }
};


Great. It resolved part of the issue: now page loads and I get response from API.
But error in Docker logs persist and page loading takes too long. With API call made it's 8.5s, without API call is 560ms.
Why does it act like that?

@ADEXITUM some content is rendered using SSR, so might be that the content is getting generated on the server partially, so that the pages load faster! its a good thing, since the page will load faster!
